# How do I capture the URL of each job so I can open full job description when looking at csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can someone help me modify this script so that it also scraps the URL associated with each job. The purpose would be when browsing the .csv file in a spreadsheet I can click on the link if I would like to know more information about the job. Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def extract(page):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
    url= f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Dispensary&l=Denver%2C+CO&radius={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard')
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find('a').text.strip()
        company = item.find('span', class_ = 'company').text.strip()
        try:
            salary = item.find('span', class_ = 'salaryText').text.strip()
        except:
            salary = ''
        summary = item.find('div', class_ = 'summary').text.strip().replace('\n', '')
        
        job = {
            'title': title,
            'company': company,
            'salary': salary,
            'summary': summary
            
            }
        joblist.append(job)
    return
        

joblist = []

for i in range(0,90,10):
    print(f'Getting page, {i}')
    c = extract(0)
    transform(c)

df = pd.DataFrame(joblist)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('jobs.csv')
```

Comment: it is not good idea to use external variable `joblist` in `transform` - better send it explicitly as  argument `def transform(soup, joblist):`

Comment: `item.find('a')['href']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of this

```
url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a')['href']
url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a').get('href')
url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a').attrs['href']
url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a').attrs.get('href')
```

---

BTW:

You always load the same page. To get next page you have to use `start=...` in url.
And you can do this more readable using dictionary and `params=` in  `requests`

```
payload = {
    'q': 'Dispensary',
    'l': 'Denver,+CO',
    'radius': 0,
    'start': page,    
}

url= 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs'

r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

---

Working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def extract(start):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    }
    
    payload = {
        'q': 'Dispensary',
        'l': 'Denver,+CO',
        'radius': 0,
        'start': start,    
    }
    
    url= 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs'
    
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    
    return soup


def transform(soup, joblist):
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard')
    
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find('a').text.strip()
        
        url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a')['href']
        #url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a').get('href')
        #url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a').attrs['href']
        #url = 'https://www.indeed.com' + item.find('a').attrs.get('href')

        company = item.find('span', class_ = 'company').text.strip()
        
        try:
            salary = item.find('span', class_ = 'salaryText').text.strip()
        except:
            salary = ''
        
        summary = item.find('div', class_ = 'summary').text.strip().replace('\n', '')
        
        joblist.append({
            'title': title,
            'url': url,
            'company': company,
            'salary': salary,
            'summary': summary
        })
        
# --- main ---

joblist = []

for start in range(0, 90, 10):
    print('Getting page', start)
    c = extract(start)
    transform(c, joblist)

df = pd.DataFrame(joblist)
df.to_csv('jobs.csv')
print(df.head())
```